# Controller for robotic arm in computer vision system

Tags: c++, c, controller, robotics

I'm working on a project of building a computer vision system. I have an embedded computer (Matrox 4Sight GPm) for running a C++ (OpenCV) program which I tested it with my laptop's built-in camera and it works.

And the idea is that when the certain conditions are met, the vision system will output a signal to trigger a robotic arm to perform a task.

Since I'm learning things from scratch, I wonder do I need an extra controller for controlling the arm?

If yes, what do I need to add in my computer vision coding part and how's the controller's code will look like (in C or C++) so that the vision can communicate with the controller to control the robotic arm?

If no (the embedded computer can control the robotic arm), what code do I need to add to make it happen?

I know this is a vague question,  but any direction for me to look into will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: this is a C++ question, please remove the `c` tag

Comment: Most of the controllers are coded in C, that's why I also include C. And ppl who are familiar with C and controller might have some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the datasheet of **Matrox 4Sight GPm** and it seems a very powerful platform.
It has one **RS-232** and one **RS-485** port for serial communication, and also consists of one **FPGA** with **Digital I/O's** that can take input commands from **Intel HM76 PCH** processor.

In my opinion, an extra microcontroller should not be needed to drive a robotic arm. If robotic arm consists of simple D.C. motors, you need to figure out how to control the **Digital I/O's** of FPGA and interface a simple motor driver IC such as **L293D** or **L298** to that **Digital I/O's**.

If the robotic arm consists of servo motors then, in that case, you definitely need a microcontroller which has **PWM** on it. You need to program the **RS-232** of **Matrox 4Sight GPm** to send some custom commands to the microcontroller on the **UART** and you can write a simple program for microcontroller to drive the servo motors of that arm using **PWM** depending on the command received over the **RS-232** serial channel from **Matrox 4Sight GPm**.

I hope I have cleared some of your doubts.

Comment: thank you very much! I will definitely look into those things you mentioned!